# Pytorch multiple gatherings

Tags: pytorch

torch.gather could help in the following case,

```
out[i][j][k] = input[index[i][j][k]][j][k]  # if dim == 0
out[i][j][k] = input[i][index[i][j][k]][k]  # if dim == 1
out[i][j][k] = input[i][j][index[i][j][k]]  # if dim == 2
```

However, what we do when we have multiple index tensors?

```
source = torch.ones(dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4)
index1 = torch.ones(dim3, dim4)
index2 = torch.ones(dim3, dim4)

for i in range(dim3):
    for j in range(dim4):
        ret[i, j] = source[index1[i, j], index2[i, j],i, j]
```

Comment: I find your question is rather unclear, would you make it clearer?

Comment: I am quite positive there is no pytorch function to do it like that, but with some reshaping trick it may be achievable, I will have a look at it. I see you have asked the question on pytorch forum as well, can you cross reference the issues ? So that if it solved on one forum, people from the other will have access to the answer as well :)